# How to scroll behavior NOT smooth in Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, scroll, vue-router, router

I'm working with Vue.js and vue router, in router.js I added the `scrollBehavior` to make every page scroll to top.
It works fine, but the `behavior` is set automatically to `'smooth'`, so my question is: **is there a way to make the behavior NOT smooth?**
I tried setting it to `behavior: 'auto'`, but it doesn't work.
Thank you!

Comment: Auto is the proper one. The issue may come from somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe some css?

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: Have you tried, just: `html { scroll-behavior: auto; }`
Use the browser tools, to check it's not being overridden by another library